# How do I get a JRE file for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, java

Background:
In my Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard, I've downloaded the Eclipse and Android SDKs. I started on a Hello World tutorial provided by Eclipse, but a dialog insists it can't find a JRE.

After a bit of searching the web, I learned that it should be in the eclipse/jre/ folder, but that folder does not exist on my system. I downloaded the Java for Mac OSX 10.6 package from the Apple Developer site, and still see no jre files.

Supposedly it is should be provided by Java. No use writing the file in eclipse.ini if I can't find the file in the first place.

This page indicates that the Max OS X already has the JRE, but I can't find the file to link to it: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jre.php

I have installed Android, Eclipse, ADT, AVD, PhoneGap.

Summary:
Need JRE.

Answer (score 4):

Try */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home*
Alternatively check */System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/* for other versions.
For Mac OS X VMs there should be *Home* at the end of the location.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the OS X version of Eclipse, unpack it, and start the Eclipse.app executable and then be able to write runnable Java programs as Java is available by default in OS X.

If you cannot start Eclipse.app, then my guess would be that you downloaded the wrong version of Eclipse.  Be certain it is the 32-bit version offered on the http://eclipse.org/downloads/ page as it should run on all 10.6 machines.

If you *can* start Eclipse.app, and you can type in programs, but you cannot run them, please take a screen dump of your Eclipse -> Preferences page placed on the Java->Installed JRE's panel.

Comment: I've already downloaded Eclipse for the Mac and it is working. However, I just need the JRE file. Are you saying that the JRE file is supposed to be included with the Eclipse download?

Comment: @Steve, the JRE is the Java Runtime Environment (as opposed to JDK).  Perhaps you need an _Android_ JRE?

Comment: I need a JRE file in the eclipse/jre folder. I'm new enough not to know what that involves, sorry. Is an Android JRE supposed to be there?

Comment: The Eclipse -> Preferences for the Installed JRE panel is simply blank.

Comment: Delete your current Eclipse folder, and unpack it again.

Answer (score 0):

From your post it sounds like you can launch Eclipse ok?

If you can launch Eclipse you have a working JRE.

Eclipse picks up the JRE from your system, or if it finds nothing it looks for a jre folder in the same directory as the Eclipse executable.

So it sounds like your JRE is *somewhere* on your system (otherwise Eclipse wouldn't start), but for some reason you do not have any pre-defined in the Installed JRE preference page.
Here's how you can find the JRE eclipse is using to bootstrap, and set it up as one to use:

In Eclipse 3.6.1:

Have a look in Help->About Eclipse SDK

Click "Installation Details"

Go to the Configuration tab

There should be a reference to the JRE in there - e.g. on mine:
-vm
~/personal dev/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/../jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so

Once you've found that, open up Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and add a new one to point to the location you found (eg on mine it is ~/Desktop/personal dev/jdk1.6.0_24)

Comment: I copied those contents into a text file to search it for JRE. The most likely culprits are these 2 lines: /instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathVariable.JRE_LIB=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar      org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6

Comment: Did you find anything for eclipse.vm in that file?    also /S­ystem/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/ seems like a likely location for a JRE - did you try pointing to that location as an installed JRE (what is at that location?)